# Calling a C++ function from Java

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I am working on a project(in Java) in which I need to evaluate user codes which may be written in C++ or Java. To evaluate a code, I need to pass a parameter to the code and get the return value from it. I can easily do it for Java codes; just create an object for the user's class and then call the function using the object. I have problems doing it for C++.

What are the possible methods I can call a C++ function from Java and get its return value? My code looks something like this (I cannot give exact code here).
**C++ code**

```
#include<stdio>
int[] function(int a[]) { } // A Simple function that takes 
                            //an array and reverses it and returns it`
```

**Java Code from where the above function is called**

```
int a[]; //The array I will pass
int rev[] = Somehow call C++ code from here and pass array a to it.
```

I read it internet that JNI can be used, but it DOES NOT allow me to use the existing code, it asks to change the int arrays to jint. Is there any way I can achieve my purpose? I just want to pass an array to an existing C++ code and get its return value.

Comment: Code a wrapper that transforms from `jint` to `int`

Comment: @BobJarvis : This is calling a C++ method from Java and not the other way round. I have also written one of the ways I found on the internet and why I am not using it

Comment: @SJuan76 : Could you please elaborate ?

Answer (score 3):

Utilizing JNI will accomplish your task: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/

Java code:

```
package test;

public class PerformWork 
{
public PerformWork()
{

}

public native int[] utilizeArray( int[] arr);

public int[] performWork(int[] arr)
{
    int[] results = utilizeArray(arr);
    return results;
}
}
```

After compiling, utilize `javah` to create your native header file

`javah -classpath <location_of_classes> test.PerformWork`

test_PerformWork.h

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class test_PerformWork */

#ifndef _Included_test_PerformWork
#define _Included_test_PerformWork
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     test_PerformWork
 * Method:    utilizeArray
 * Signature: ([I)[I
 */
JNIEXPORT jintArray JNICALL Java_test_PerformWork_utilizeArray
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jintArray);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

Lastly, implement the native function

```
#include "test_PerformWork.h"

JNIEXPORT jintArray JNICALL Java_test_PerformWork_utilizeArray(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance, jintArray arr)
{
jboolean isCopy = FALSE;
jsize lengthOfArr = env->GetArrayLength(arr);
jint * arrPtr = env->GetIntArrayElements(arr, &isCopy);

//call your built in function
int result[] = {1,2,3,4};
const jint * resultPtr = (const jint *)result;
jintArray javaResult = env->NewIntArray(lengthOfArr);
env->SetIntArrayRegion(javaResult, 0, lengthOfArr, resultPtr);

return javaResult;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the `Java Native Interface` or `JNI`.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But as I mentioned, the user has already submitted the codes to me. I cannot modify that code, as JNI would ask for a return value of jnitArray and not simply the int array that the user would have returned. Is there any way around from there ?

Comment: Then you will have to wrap it and call it from something that sits in between.

Comment: @user3215014  You will need to use JNI to create a function, in C++, for Java to call.  From that new function, call your existing C++ code, and format the results for Java.  You will then package both the existing C++ code and your new C++ Java function into a single library, for which Java will then load and invoke.

Comment: @Samhain and it should be an answer

Answer (score 0):

The person asking the question clearly cannot relink his running java executable. And would not want to do so with code that has been submitted by users for review, as this code could easily crash the jvm.

It seems like the correct answer is to compile the user provided code into a .o file then link it with pre-written 'main' program which calls the predefined method name, passing whatever parameters sets are necessary for testing and evaluation. This standalone native executable can be easily invoked from within the java (web) application and the results given back to the user.